# Can I stop partition deletion in "Disks" Utility?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I have a dual boot system.  Deepin/Ubuntu.  Ubuntu is what I use mostly.  Deepin was there to have a look at and play with.  However, it hasn't been getting good use and was causing some headaches I won't go into here.

So I thought, maybe I'll just remove it. I started Ubuntu's graphical 'disks' utility. Selected my 120GB SSD drive, highlighted /dev/sdb8 (I thought) and clicked the '-' icon.

'Are you sure?' it asked.

'Yeah, why not', I said.

...

Aiiieeeee...Now it just says 120GB unallocated space.

Now, the disks utility is still open and I am typing this from the system running Ubuntu. I would rather not have to do a backup and reinstall. Obviously, the changes haven't been 100% committed yet.

Is there a way to come back from this? Or have I already stepped off the cliff and just have some time before I hit bottom?

Comment: You can use `testdisk` to recover partitions. It's best to do it from a live system.

Comment: Wait a minute, Ubuntu won't delete a partition that's currently in use. Are you sure it has 120GB available space?

Comment: I think you have two alternatives, restore from backup and try to recover with some recovery tool. You can try with TestDisk, but if it does not work, don't spend too much time trying. Restoring to an SSD should be rather fast.

Comment: @wjandrea It says, 120GB unallocated space/free space...but yes, that includes the 60GB previously allocated for the partition *currently in use* as well as the 60GB that was for Deepin. Obviously, things are still working but I'm fairly sure reboot would commit.

Comment: Also, do you mean that I can use TestDisk (or equivalent) to just restore the partition table (I have used it for photo file recovery only) and that I should shutdown normally (committing changes?) before doing so?

Comment: Upon shutdown & boot (to liveUSB gparted) I saw that my root partition still existed, despite what the 'Disks' utility indicated. I booted again and got a grub error prompt.  Fiddled with that and was able to boot into Ubuntu.  Went back and re-did the repartitioning with gparted. So... never found out if there was a way I could have reverted the changes before rebooting, but problem solved anyway.

Comment: @MrFinn restoring the partition table is the exact main point of Testdisk. Other features are just additions. :) If you solved the problem you should write a self answer.

Comment: @MrFinn How strange. You might want to check if your hard drive is failing.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I solved my problem but did not answer my question.I wondered if there were a way to safely roll back the changes without rebooting.  I solved my problem by rebooting.  And using the suggestions in the comments.  Thanks all.